# php CMS, the code is working from index.php, but it is not working from deeper CMS project folder

Tags: php, content-management-system, recurrence

I have simple recurrent function to output array values to the webpage. It works perfectly if i use it from `cms3\index.php`  . But is works only partially (the first round) if i use it from `cms34\ww.admin\pages\menu.php`.

I am looking through the book:
"CMS Design Using PHP and jQuery",
https://www.packtpub.com/web-develop...php-and-jquery
On chapter three they give simple CMS example.

The script below should read database and generate hyperlinks to two webpages.

```
// cms34\ww.admin\pages\menu.php
<?php
echo '<div id="pages-wrapper">';
$rs=dbAll('select id,type,name,parent from pages order by ord,name');
$pages=array();
foreach($rs as $r){
    if(!isset($pages[$r['parent']]))$pages[$r['parent']]=array();
    $pages[$r['parent']][]=$r;
}
function show_pages($id,$pages){
    if(!isset($pages[$id]))return;
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($pages[$id] as $page){
        echo '<li id="page_'.$page['id'].'"><a href="pages.php?id='.$page['id'].'">';
        echo '<ins>&nbsp;</ins>'.htmlspecialchars($page['name']).'</a>';
        show_pages($page['id'],$pages);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
show_pages(0,$pages);
echo '</div>';
```

This is the same script with added `print_r` for debugging.

```
<?php

echo '<div id="pages-wrapper">';
$rs=dbAll('select id,type,name,parent from pages order by ord,name');
print_r('<br> in menu.php rs=').print_r($rs);
$pages=array();
foreach($rs as $r){
        print_r('<br> in menu.php before if r=').print_r($r);
    if(!isset($pages[$r['parent']]))$pages[$r['parent']]=array();
    $pages[$r['parent']][]=$r;
        print_r('<br> in menu.php after if r=').print_r($r).print_r('  ;;r[parent][0]=').print_r($r['parent'][0]);
}
function show_pages($id,$pages){
    print_r('<br> in menu.php function show_pages, $id =').print_r($id);
    print_r('<br> in menu.php function show_pages, $pages =').print_r($pages);
    print_r('<br> in menu.php function show_pages, $pages[$id] =').print_r($pages[$id]);
    if(!isset($pages[$id]))return;
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($pages[$id] as $page){
            print_r('<br> in menu.php foreach ').print_r(htmlspecialchars($page['name']));
        echo '<li id="page_'.$page['id'].'"><a href="pages.php?id='.$page['id'].'">';
        echo '<ins>&nbsp;</ins>'.htmlspecialchars($page['name']).'</a>';
        show_pages($page['id'],$pages);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
show_pages(0,$pages);
echo '</div>';
```

This is how webpage looks:

```
 rs=Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 24 [type] => 0 [name] => Home [parent] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 35 [type] => 0 [name] => Home2 [parent] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 36 [type] => 0 [name] => test [parent] => 24 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 38 [type] => 0 [name] => test3 [parent] => 24 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 25 [type] => 0 [name] => Second Page [parent] => 0 ) )
in menu.php before if r=Array ( [id] => 24 [type] => 0 [name] => Home [parent] => 0 )
in menu.php after if r=Array ( [id] => 24 [type] => 0 [name] => Home [parent] => 0 ) ;;r[parent][0]=0
in menu.php before if r=Array ( [id] => 35 [type] => 0 [name] => Home2 [parent] => 0 )
in menu.php after if r=Array ( [id] => 35 [type] => 0 [name] => Home2 [parent] => 0 ) ;;r[parent][0]=0
in menu.php before if r=Array ( [id] => 36 [type] => 0 [name] => test [parent] => 24 )
in menu.php after if r=Array ( [id] => 36 [type] => 0 [name] => test [parent] => 24 ) ;;r[parent][0]=2
in menu.php before if r=Array ( [id] => 38 [type] => 0 [name] => test3 [parent] => 24 )
in menu.php after if r=Array ( [id] => 38 [type] => 0 [name] => test3 [parent] => 24 ) ;;r[parent][0]=2
in menu.php before if r=Array ( [id] => 25 [type] => 0 [name] => Second Page [parent] => 0 )
in menu.php after if r=Array ( [id] => 25 [type] => 0 [name] => Second Page [parent] => 0 ) ;;r[parent][0]=0
in menu.php function show_pages, $id =0
in menu.php function show_pages, $pages =Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 24 [type] => 0 [name] => Home [parent] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 35 [type] => 0 [name] => Home2 [parent] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 25 [type] => 0 [name] => Second Page [parent] => 0 ) ) [24] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 36 [type] => 0 [name] => test [parent] => 24 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 38 [type] => 0 [name] => test3 [parent] => 24 ) ) )
in menu.php function show_pages, $pages[$id] =Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 24 [type] => 0 [name] => Home [parent] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 35 [type] => 0 [name] => Home2 [parent] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 25 [type] => 0 [name] => Second Page [parent] => 0 ) )
```

As you can see, data are fetched from the database. But the recurrent function `show_pages($id,$pages)` is not executed the second round. I mean this part of `show_page` function is not executed:

```
  foreach($pages[$id] as $page){
            print_r('<br> in menu.php foreach ').print_r(htmlspecialchars($page['name']));
        echo '<li id="page_'.$page['id'].'"><a href="pages.php?id='.$page['id'].'">';
        echo '<ins>&nbsp;</ins>'.htmlspecialchars($page['name']).'</a>';
        show_pages($page['id'],$pages);
        echo '</li>';
    }

In CMS i go to:
http://localhost/cms34/ww.admin/index.php
which requires 'pages.php';
which requires 'header.php' and 'pages/menu.php';

the header.php requires 'admin_libs.php',
which requires require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cms34/ww.incs/basics.php';
which has __autoload, and DB connection functions.
```

`pages/menu.php` is shown in the question above. It gets data about webpages from the table:

```
$rs=dbAll('select id,type,name,parent from pages order by ord,name');
```

and than executes recurrent function to generate hyperlinks.

If i copy everything from `pages/menu.php` to `cms34\index.php`
and prepend line:

```
//this line included file for DB connention and data retrieving functions
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cms34/ww.incs/basics.php';
```

The hyperlinks are generated and recurrent function is working.
But if i try to use code from `cms34\ww.admin\pages\menu.php` from CMS, it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

It started working without a reason. Do not know why, but it was not working yesterday.  If anybody could explain what could be the reason and how to resolve it faster than waiting a day, i would appreciate a lot.